In C#, I'm trying to iterate strings in single loop, how?
I'm trying to achieve this output:
LOWEST LOW MEDIUM HIGH HIGHEST HIGHEST HIGH MEDIUM LOW LOWEST

I know there are many ways to do it, but I'm trying it in single loop, is it achievable?
My code is basically like this:
class Program {
    static void Main()
    {
        string[] phases = ["LOWEST", "LOW", "MEDIUM", "HIGH", "HIGHEST"];
        int fullRotation = (phases.Length - 1) * 2;
        for (int i = 0; i <= fullRotation; i++)
        {
            int index;
            if (i <= (phases.Length - 1))
            {
                index = i;
            }
            else
            {
                index = fullRotation - i;
            }

            Console.Write(phases[index] + " ");
        }
    }
}

I'm getting:
LOWEST LOW MEDIUM HIGH HIGHEST HIGH MEDIUM LOW LOWEST


You have 5 entries, so you need 10 indexes, not 9. Also, you need to come up with a function that takes inputs from for example 0 to 9 and gives you an output of 0 to 4 and then 4 to 0. That's it.

^^ https://dotnetfiddle.net/cL1n5l, also works on even-length array: https://dotnetfiddle.net/amXUXF

If you were using two loops the code would be much more clear.  Why the requirement?

Your loop has fullRotation + 1 (i.e. (phases.Length - 1) * 2 + 1) iterations because of the <= comparison. But it should have one more iteration than that (i.e. (phases.Length) * 2).
I would do:
int fullRotation = phases.Length * 2;
for (int i = 0; i < fullRotation; i++)

This loop now has phases.Length * 2 iterations. But the calculation in the else branch is now off-by-1, so you should also subtract 1:
else {
    index = fullRotation - i - 1;
    //                      ^^^^
}


I appreciate that instead of changing the whole code, you just corrected my provided code. A big thank you man!

When querying, I suggest using Linq; in our case
string[] phases = ["LOWEST", "LOW", "MEDIUM", "HIGH", "HIGHEST"];

we want to iterate forward and then backward:
var query = phases            // <- forward
  .Concat(phases.Reverse());  // <- backward

having query, we can build the final string with a help of string.Join:
var result = string.Join(" ", query);

Combining all together:
using System.Linq;

class Program {
  static void Main() {
    string[] phases = ["LOWEST", "LOW", "MEDIUM", "HIGH", "HIGHEST"];

    Console.Write(string.Join(" ", phases.Concat(phases.Reverse())));
  }
}

Please, fiddle yourself.

You can use string functions instead of loops. Here I am using Join and Reverse
var result = string.Join(" ", phases) + " " + string.Join(" ", phases.Reverse());

OR (much simpler version)
var result = string.Join(" ", phases.Concat(phases.Reverse()));

OR (using single for loop)
var result = "";
var length = phases.Length;

for (int i = 0; i < 2 * length; i++)
{
     if (i < length)
     {
           result += phases[i] + " ";
     }
     else
     {
           result += phases[2 * length - 1 - i] + (i == 2 * length - 1 ? "" : " ");
     }
 }


string[] phases = ["LOWEST", "LOW", "MEDIUM", "HIGH", "HIGHEST"];
for (int i = 0; i < phases.Length*2; i++)
{
    if (i < phases.Length)
    {
        Console.Write(phases[i]+" ");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.Write(phases[phases.Length * 2 - 1 - i] + " ");
    }
}

Test


Let's break down your problem:
You have array of 5 elements, which have indexes from 0 to 4. Obvious.
You want to iterate it twice (from start to end and reverse), so you would need 10 iterations (5 elements one way, and 5 elements opposite way).
You have defined int fullRotation = (phases.Length - 1) * 2; which in our case equals to 8. It's is less than 10, BUT you use inclusive loop bounds, so from 0 to fullRotation inclusive, resulting in 9 iterations. But THIS IS STILL LESS THAN needed 10 iterations.
You can already see, where the bug originates.
When index of the loop i reaches value of 4, it will use last element (if (i <= (phases.Length - 1)) is satisfied).
After that, i flips to 5, and then we reach this line index = fullRotation - i which gives 3 as a result. So it is used to access second to last item.
Then, as expected, i goes down to 0, so prints first item in array at the end - all good.
So here we have our bug detected and to fix it we can just tweak your code a little:
int fullRotation = phases.Length * 2 - 1

The change is just putting -1 outside the brackets - because purpose of this subtraction is to account for additional index at 0 position. That's why we need to apply it "once".
